# how to make question with passive structure?

Tags: grammar

what is the rule for making questions based on passive structure?

for example:

> TV was invented by X.

question:

> who was TV invented by?

this question structure confuses me!

Comment: Your question is grammatical if you insist on using the passive, but "Who invented TV?" would be more natural.